# wordpress mu infiny loop on global admin

Tags: wordpress, mu

I'm working on a wordpress mu 4.0.1

I migrated it from a dev server to a prod server and now I'm having infinite 302 Moved Temporarily loop when accessing the global site admin menu.
All path seem to be correct.
Everything works fine in dev server. :/

here is the htacces file I use :

```
# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes 

# Stop access to sensitive files
<Files .htaccess> 
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
 Satisfy all
</Files>  

<Files readme.html> 
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
 Satisfy all
</Files> 

<Files wp-config.php> 
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
 Satisfy all
</Files> 

<Files php.ini> 
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
 Satisfy all
</Files>  

<FilesMatch "^(error_log)$"> 
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
 Satisfy all
</FilesMatch> 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

And here is the end of the wp-config.php file :

```
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

define ('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.chs-yonne.fr');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

/** Réglage des variables de WordPress et de ses fichiers inclus. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Thanks for your watches !

Pierre.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After testing some updates on the database and check the wp-admin/network/admin.php file, I found that in the wp_blogs table, the field "domain" must match with the constant "DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE" of the .htaccess file (o_O)

Why putting "www" in a field called "domain" ??? I don't know !